# Proving the Identity Type Has a Term

Tags: type-theory

I am trying to get used to type theory.  I have a two things to ask.  Let $1$ be the unit type with unique term $\star : 1$.  As an exercise I was trying to prove that 
$$
\prod_{A:\mathcal{U}}[(1\rightarrow A)=A]
$$
has a term.  It made me realize I don't really get what's going on.  Using induction for dependent function types and equality it suffices to show that $(1\rightarrow 1)=1$ has a term.  I haven't done many proofs where I need to show that an identity type has a term.  The ones I have done are either by showing that the two terms are judgementally equal or by defining a function type into the identity type from a type known to have a term.

So, I am interested to hear two things:

1. What are the different standard methods to show that an identity type has a term (apart from those I mentioned)?
2. How can I prove or disprove the exercise above?

Comment: Equality of types is not defined in ordinary type theory. You'll need something like the univalence axiom.

Comment: @ZhenLin My confusion is deep indeed.  Isn't every type a term of some universe?

Comment: Sure. So what? There are no rules in type theory that tell you what equality of types "really" means, so the only equalities you will be able to prove will be trivial in some sense. This one is non-trivial.